# Overriding isEqual and Hash with properties of mixed data types

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, equality, nsobject

I have a custom class and I am trying to check if 2 objects of that class is equal. I tried using isEqual and '==' ways to test it, but both returns false even if the objects are same.

Say I have a class named MyClass which has some properties:

***MyClass.h***

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger
{
    black = 0,
    white = 1,
    red = 2,
    blue = 3
} Color;

typedef enum : NSUInteger
{
    ModelA = 0,
    ModelB = 1,
    ModelC = 2
} ModelType;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) Color color;
@property (nonatomic, assign) ModelType model;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@end
```

***MyClass.m***

```
@implementation MyClass
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.color = White;
        self.model = ModelA;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(NSObject *)object
{
    MyClass *filter = (MyClass *)object;
    return [self.name isEqualToString:object.name] && self.color == object.color &&
           self.model == object.model;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    return [self.name hash] ^ [self.color hash] ^ [self.model hash];
}

@end
```

***Question:***
This is throwing `bad receiver type 'Color'` error on hash method. I am guessing its because I am trying to do XOR of a string with an integer? Am I doing the hash logic right? How do I create a hash of string and integers?

***Solution:***

I was able to figure out what the issue was. Here is the solution:

```
- (NSUInteger)hash
    {
        return [self.name hash] ^ [[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.color] hash] ^ [[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.model] hash];
    }
```

Comment: Okay I got what the issue was. Solution: [self.name hash] ^ [[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.color] hash] ^ [[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.model] hash];

Comment: Huge overkill. Just use `[self.name hash]`. You don't have to include everything in the hash.

Comment: XOR-ing is not a good solution. Use `return 31*31*[self.name hash] + 31*[[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.color] hash] + [[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.model] hash];` for better distribution of hashes.
`

Comment: If you are going to include everything, why not drop the use of NSNumber and simply use the raw enum value?

Comment: @rmaddy - What do you mean by simply using raw enum values? I tried [self.color hash] and I was getting error. Could you please provide some example?

Comment: @techie_woman Just use `[self.name hash] ^ self.color ^ self.model;`. It's possible you will actually need `[self.name hash] ^ (NSUInteger)self.color ^ (NSUInteger)self.model;`.